# Intent and Broadcast Receiver trouble

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having trouble sending and receiving an intent.  The relevant code is below... I can't find anything wrong with it. I'm not positive what to put there...  Right now the intent is broadcasted and the receiver never catches the permissions one.  The Sms works fine however.  Could it possibly be the manifest? I'm thinking it has something to do with the action...

PS. I know the spelling mistake in my naming... lol

In a service:

```
public final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

textFilter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
textFilter.addAction("ADD_NUMBER_TO_PERMISSIONS");


registerReceiver(incomingReciever,textFilter);

BroadcastReceiver incomingReciever = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent _intent) {
        if(_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            //do some stuff
            }   
        if(_intent.getAction().equals("ADD_NUMBER_TO_PERMISSIONS")) {   
                //do some stuff
            }
        }   
    }   
};
```

---

Then in a different activity.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent("ADD_NUMBER_TO_PERMISSIONS");
resultIntent.putExtra("NameAndNumber", contact);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
sendBroadcast(resultIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are registering your broadcast in onResume() and unregistering it in onPause() of your activity.

Also you may need the following code after  in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission>
```

Comment: I'll try that out, it very well could be whats wrong.  And yeah I have that permission.... the SMS broadcast is being received fine, which is what is confusing me.

Comment: Try adding the toString() method after getAction():   _intent.getAction().toString().equals()

Comment: Hm.. That didn't work either. Thanks for the suggestions though this bug is driving me crazy.

Comment: Hmmm, usually when I name my intent actions I put the package name in front of the intent.  So if it were in a package called com.mypackage I would call the action "com.mypackage.intent.action.ADD_NUMBER_TO_PERMISSIONS" instead of ADD_NUMBER_TO_PERMISSIONS.  I don't think this will make a difference but it's worth a shot.

Comment: That seems like a good idea, I'll try that later today when I can

Comment: fixed it... I had my second if statement still in the first if statement. The amount of headache caused by something that stupid.......